# Prawn PDF and muliplte records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I'm looking to extract all records to a single pdf using Prawn PDF and rails 4.2.

Currently I have them generating by id for individual pdf's and works well.

Show

```
def show
    @agreement = Agreement.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        pdf = AgreementPdf.new(@agreement)
        send_data pdf.render, filename: "Agreement - #{@agreement.entity}", type: "application/pdf", disposition: "inline"
      end
    end
  end
```

Index in table

```
<% @agreements.each do |agreement| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= agreement.entity %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Download', agreement_path(agreement.id, format: 'pdf'), :target => "_blank" %></td>
            </tr>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to add a route with the path of the new method:

```html
get '/agreements/all_records' => 'agreements#all_records', :as => :agreement_all_records
```

Then call the methods with in the view:

```html
<td><%= link_to 'Download All Records', agreement_all_records_path(), :target => "_blank" %></td>
```

It will look something like this in the controllers:

```html
def all_records

  @agreements = Agreement.all

  pdf = AgreementsPdf.new(@agreements)
  send_data pdf.render,filename:'agreements.pdf',type:'application/pdf', disposition: 'inline'
end
```

And the Report may look like this ( assuming that agreement model has id,name fields ):

```html
require 'prawn/table'

class AgreementsPdf < PdfReport
  TABLE_WIDTHS = [100, 100]
  PAGE_MARGIN = [40, 40, 40, 40]


  def initialize(agreements=[])
    super(:page_size => "LEGAL",  margin: PAGE_MARGIN, :page_layout => :landscape)
    @agreements = agreements
    display_table
  end

  private

  def display_table
    if table_data.empty?
      text "None data"
    else
      table(table_data,column_widths: TABLE_WIDTHS, :cell_style => { size: 10 } )       
    end
  end

  def table_data
    @table_data ||= @agreements.map { |e| [e.id, e.name] }
  end

end
```

Hope this will give you an idea

Comment: How would you call the variable in the view?

Comment: I edit the answer and add the view and route. I have not tested, is just code to show how to do it

Comment: Nailed it. Thanks for your help.